# For a 2D array in Java Script How do you find ALL indexesOf value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have a 2D array and a function that will return the index of value Q. How can I write the function so that I can get AllIndexOfQ? So if I am looking for "dog" I will get [0,0],[1,2],[3,1],[3,2]

```js
var arr = Array(['dog', 'cat', 'fish'], ['fish', 'fish', 'dog'], ['cat', 'tiger', 'fish'], ['cat', 'dog', 'dog']);

function getIndexOfQ(data, q) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var index = data[i].indexOf(q);
    if (index > -1) {
      return [i, index];
    }
  }
}

var a = getIndexOfQ(arr, "dog");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: You can return only a single value from a function. Push the values you get in the loop to an array, and return that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `return`, push to an array instead. Also, `indexOf` isn't enough, because that won't find *all* matches, just the first match. You'll have to iterate over each item of the sub-array, and if it matches, push an array of the two indicies to the matches array:

```js
var arr = Array(['dog', 'cat', 'fish'], ['fish', 'fish', 'dog'], ['cat', 'tiger', 'fish'], ['cat', 'dog', 'dog']);

function getIndexOfQ(data, q) {
  const matches = [];
  data.forEach((arr, i) => {
    arr.forEach((item, j) => {
      if (item === q) {
        matches.push([i, j]);
      }
    });
  });
  return matches;
}

var a = getIndexOfQ(arr, "dog");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you! this helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

`arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])` according to MDN.

Which means you can loop through your array and specify a starting point each time to find all occurances.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky to write a one-liner for multiple matches

```js
const arr = [['dog', 'cat', 'fish'], ['fish', 'fish', 'dog'], ['cat', 'tiger', 'fish'], ['cat', 'dog', 'dog']];
const getIndexOfQ = (data, q) => {
  let matches = [];
  data.forEach((a, i) => { 
    a.forEach((item, j) => { if (item === q) matches.push([i, j]) }) 
  })
  return matches;
};


const a = getIndexOfQ(arr, "dog");
console.log(a);
```

Try this if you only want to find one dog in each array

```js
const arr = [['dog', 'cat', 'fish'], ['fish', 'fish', 'dog'], ['cat', 'tiger', 'fish'], ['cat', 'dog', 'dog']];

const getIndexOfQ = (data, q) => data.map(
  (item,i) => (item.indexOf(q) !==-1) ? [i,item.indexOf(q)] : false)
  .filter(item => item);

const a = getIndexOfQ(arr, "dog");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for I  marked the other answer as correct because he was first. Thank you.

Comment: By two minutes ;)